# WCF Contract Design; one large or several small contracts?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a web application that uses WCF to communicate with the back-end DB. I already have everything working but I was wondering if it would be better to split up my fairly large Service Contract into several Contracts.

As it stands the service contract is a single general file with all operations contained within it. I know I could break it up into smaller contracts that are assocaited with the Data Objects in my business logic i.e. A Person object has a PersonContract etc.,

I am just worried that the web application will have to reference several WCF Services instead of the one and suffer as a result of this. Will having several smaller contracts in anyway affect performance, either negatively or positively?

Thanks.

Comment: If you set the contracts up as different front doors, (i.e. one binary, multiple interfaces) you're unlikely to see much impact. If you go for more extensive segregation the impact will depend on your use cases (for separate binaries, rarely used services can be unloaded to free server resources for example). If you have dependencies you also need to decide how to interact between different services i.e. via the service layer (segragated, but adds overhead) or via lower level interfaces (some would argue this may lead to tightly coupled services). It may be a case of if it makes sense, try it.

Comment: @forsvarir I am going to go ahead and implement it. It does make sense to do it and I was just curious if it would cause me any issues due to the number of references. Although if it does I imagine it will be minimal. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and [Interface Segregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) principle (the "S" and "I" in SOLID) still applies to WCF Service Contracts.

The nature of refactoring would depend largely on what type of services you offer, e.g.

- Data Services => You would typically consolidate each web service around main business entities.
- Enterprise Business Services => Would typically consolidate groups of services around main business process themes (e.g. claims processing or order processing services)

But in summary, don't be shy to refactor your services (especially if you can forsee new Operations being added in future), and also take any opportunity to refactor and reuse any common theme in the interfaces.

Edit : Apologies - w.r.t. Q about performance wasn't answered. If you do find the overhead of multiple services problematic, you could compromise with one / few service(s), with many interfaces each, as in this [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767588/wcf-optimal-performance-settings). With a proxy, facade or service agent type pattern on the client, you could 'hide' the fact that your are in fact speaking to just the one / few services.

Comment: Whilst your point may be valid, I don't see how it addresses the concerns raised: `I am just worried that the web application will have to reference several WCF Services instead of the one and suffer as a result of this. Will having several smaller contracts in anyway affect performance, either negatively or positively?`

Comment: I am all for refactoring and making the code more resuable, my main concern was if having several web references in my web site project will make it run slower. Thanks for the advice though.